# How can I remove an image that is drawn on the screen and release all links so ARC will reclaim?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I have an animated clock, which presently has a memory leak. I seem at present to be able to put things on top of an image, but not take it away or necessarily clear it (apart from redrawing the whole clock so the second hand is not at two different locations).

The code intended to clear clock components is:

```
for(UIView *image in self.toWipe)
{
    [image removeFromSuperview];
}
[self.toWipe removeAllObjects];
```

The code that draws the second hand (treatment of hour and minute is the same) is:

```
CGAffineTransform secondTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(centerX, centerY);
secondTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(secondTransform, -10, -189);
secondTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(secondTransform, seconds / 60.0 * M_PI * 2.0);
UIImageView *secondHandView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:secondHandImage];
secondHandView.transform = secondTransform;
[self.view addSubview:secondHandView];
[self.toWipe addObject:secondHandView];
[self.toWipe addObject:secondHandImage];
```

I have masked the drawn second hand not erasing itself by drawing the clock face at each iteration; if I don't do that, the second hand (or others) will sweep out a growing slice of pie until they reach a 360° filled-in disk. The memory grows, slowly but steadily, and the second hand gets choppier in its motion.

Is there anything else I can or should be doing to consign used objects to oblivion? I'm using ARC in this project; I would like to know what else more or differently I could be giving so the memory leak is fixed.

Thanks,

--EDIT--

The following, with cruft commented out and cruft not commented out, is the method body. It does not address exceptions, and no exception is raised from anything in the body:

```
int height = floor([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height + .4);
int width = floor([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width + .4);
UIImage *backgroundImage = nil;

if (height == 2048 || height == 2008 || height == 1024 || height == 1004 || height == 984)
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))
    {
        backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Default-Portrait.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Default-Landscape.png"];
    }
}
else if (height == 1536 || height == 768 || height == 748 || height == 728)
{
    backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Default-Landscape.png"];
}
else if (height == 1136 || height == 1116 || height == 1096)
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))
    {
        backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Default-568.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Default-Rotated-568.png"];
    }
}
else if (height == 960 || height == 940 || height == 920 || height == 480 || height == 460 || height == 440)
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))
    {
        backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Default.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Default-Rotated.png"];
    }
}
else if ((height == 640 || height == 620 || height == 600) && (width == 1136 || width == 1116 || width == 1096))
{
    backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Rotated-568.png"];
}
else if ((height == 640 || height == 620 || height == 600 || height == 320 || height == 300 || height == 280) && (width == 960 || width == 940 || width == 920 || width == 480 || width == 470 || width == 410))
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))
    {
        backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Default-Portrait.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Default-Rotated.png"];
    }
}
else
{
    backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Default-Portrait.png"];

}
backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Default-Landscape.png"];


if (!UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))
{
    int juggle = height;
    height = width;
    width = juggle;
}
NSUInteger centerX = width * .5;
NSUInteger centerY = height * .5;

CGRect containerRect = CGRectZero;
containerRect.size = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

for(UIView *image in self.toWipe)
{
    [image removeFromSuperview];
}
[self.toWipe removeAllObjects];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];
//     UIView *background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Default-Landscape.png"];
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
[self.toWipe addObject:backgroundView];
self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerRect];
// float hours = 5.0;
// float minutes = 19.0;
// float seconds = 312.0;
// int timeStampMilliseconds = (ceil([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0));
// double timeStampMilliseconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0;
double timeStampMilliseconds = CACurrentMediaTime() * 1000;
double hours = fmodf(timeStampMilliseconds, 86400000) / 3600000.0;
double minutes = fmodf(timeStampMilliseconds, 3600000) / 60000.0;
double seconds = fmodf(timeStampMilliseconds, 60000) / 1000.0;
// NSLog(@"Milliseconds: %lf, Hours: %lf, minutes: %lf, seconds: %lf", timeStampMilliseconds, hours, minutes, seconds);
[self.containerView removeFromSuperview];
self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerRect];
UIImage *hourHandImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hour-hand.png"];
UIImageView *hourHandView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:hourHandImage];
hourHandImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hour-hand.png"];
hourHandView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:hourHandImage];
[self.view addSubview:hourHandView];

// UIImage *dotImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dot.png"];
// UIImageView *dotView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:dotImage];
// dotView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(centerX, centerY);
// [self.view addSubview:dotView];



hourHandView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
CGAffineTransform hourTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(centerX, centerY);
    hourTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(hourTransform, -22, -122);
    hourTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(hourTransform, hours / 12.0 * M_PI * 2.0);
    CGAffineTransform minuteTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(centerX, centerY);
    minuteTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(minuteTransform, -10, -182);
    minuteTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(minuteTransform, minutes / 60.0 * M_PI * 2.0);
    // hourTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(hourTransform, -sin(angle) * 50 + 122 , -cos(angle) * 50 + 122);


// hourTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(hourTransform, -330, 330);
hourHandView.transform = hourTransform;
[self.toWipe addObject:hourHandImage];
[self.toWipe addObject:hourHandView];
UIImage *minuteHandImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"minute-hand.png"];
UIImageView *minuteHandView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:minuteHandImage];
minuteHandView.transform = minuteTransform;
[self.view addSubview:minuteHandView];
[self.toWipe addObject:minuteHandView];
[self.toWipe addObject:minuteHandImage];

minuteTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(minuteTransform, minutes / 60.0 * M_PI * 2.0);
UIImage *secondHandImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second-hand.png"];
CGAffineTransform secondTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(centerX, centerY);
secondTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(secondTransform, -10, -189);
secondTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(secondTransform, seconds / 60.0 * M_PI * 2.0);
UIImageView *secondHandView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:secondHandImage];
secondHandView.transform = secondTransform;
[self.view addSubview:secondHandView];
[self.toWipe addObject:secondHandView];
[self.toWipe addObject:secondHandImage];



// hourHandView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(centerX, centerY);
// hourHandView.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, hour / (12.0 * M_PI * 2.0));
// UIImageView *minuteHandView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:minuteHandImage];
// UIImageView *secondHandView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:secondHandImage];

// [self.view addSubview:minuteHandView];
// [self.view addSubview:secondHandView];
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you show how you are getting secondHandImage?

Comment: This can't possibly be your actual code. You're putting a `UIImage` into `toWipe`, and then sending it `removeFromSuperview`, to which it doesn't respond; that would cause an exception.

Comment: I put three images into toWipe, and call removeFromSuperview from all of them. I'll edit my post to include the message body.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many you put in there, you _can't send `removeFromSuperview` to a `UIImage`_. It doesn't respond to that message. `toWipe` must be `nil`. Then nothing's getting added to it; thus nothing's being sent `removeFromSuperview`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just applying the transform for each second instead of removing and adding the imageview over and over again?

Here is the code that I have used for a clock app I was working on:

```
-(void)updateClock
{
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:inDate];
    NSInteger seconds = [dateComponents second];
    NSInteger minutes = [dateComponents minute];
    NSInteger hours = [dateComponents hour];
    //NSLog(@"raw: hours:%d min:%d secs:%d", hours, minutes, seconds);
    if (hours > 12) hours -=12; //PM

    //set angles for each of the hands
    CGFloat secAngle = Degrees2Radians(seconds/60.0*360);
    CGFloat minAngle = Degrees2Radians(minutes/60.0*360);

    CGFloat minAdjustment = minAngle/12.0;
    CGFloat hourAngle = Degrees2Radians(hours/12.0*360) + minAdjustment;

    //reflect the rotations + 180 degres since CALayers coordinate system is inverted
    secHand.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation (secAngle+M_PI, 0, 0, 1);
    minHand.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation (minAngle+M_PI, 0, 0, 1);
    hourHand.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation (hourAngle+M_PI, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: I've thought about it; is there a way to do so without the inaccuracies of a chain of floating point numbers? IE is there a way to say "Reset this image exactly to zero, and then rotate it the same amount as if a new one were created?"

Comment: Added question: If I "rotate forward, rotate back" n times, is the corruption in terms of number of digits O(n), or O(log n)? If it's near O(log n) or something small, I may have dismissed this approach too quickly.

Comment: I refactored my code to have an initial setup and incremental changes of views. The code is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348298/how-to-deal-with-leaks-in-ios-when-memory-consumption-climbs-but-leaks-does-not - could you take a look, not specifically at memory, but why it renders an initial view and then does not subsequently update it?

Comment: Create a strong property of NSTimer in your class. My guess is that when your render function completes, your timer is getting set to nil.